# How Use lambda in kivy bind python?

Tags: python, lambda, drop-down-menu, kivy, dropdown

I am learning to use the dropdown object with the documentation example

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

dropdown = DropDown()
for index in range(10):
    btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)

    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))

    dropdown.add_widget(btn)
mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

I know what it is a lambda function, the name of its arguments is supposed to be arbitrary as in a normal function, but in the first case the argument "btn" refers to the Button instance where it is being declared (in order to extract the text from there).

The second occurrence of lambda seems to me even more rare because it has two arguments "instance" and "X" but for the setattr only the "X" is used, I managed to print that argument and it is a

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Your two paragraphs of text appear to be the real content of the post, but don't contain any questions. And despite the post title, you don't appear to have an issue using lambda functions with Kivy.

Comment: if the arguments of a lambda function are arbitrary, why in the second lambda need the REAL name of the button I want to change? I tried using another name and don't works

Comment: The arguments to `setattr` are not arbitrary. You must provide a reference to the object that has the attribute you want to change.

Comment: The arguments of a lambda function are arbitrary, meaning that you can choose what arguments it should accept. However, like any other function, its arguments must match the arguments provided by the caller. The `on_select` method is called with the `DropDown` instance as the first argument, and the second argument come from the earlier `select` call. So your `on_select` function must accept those two arguments, even if you don't use the `instance` argument.

Comment: the first thing you said now it's clear to me, I need to make the declaration because internally any function I build will pass those two arguments. So in the last part I understand that the name "mainbutton" was added to "dropdown" when I made this `mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)` that's the only way the name "mainbutton" can be used internally in that lambda function